# Meaning of "homology" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Touraine is a region in France where supposedly the purest French is
>   spoken. You go for a visit to check it out. At the edge of a forest, a
>   remnant of a thickly forested Gaul, you meet a man who tells you: “I
>   am René Descartes.” If you are a native speaker of the same language,
>   you will know that this man has also said, in other circumstances, “I
>   think, therefore I am.” Going into the woods, you begin to meditate on
>   this strange **homology**, that is, to realize that independent of
>   circumstance, this man expressed his identity with the immutable
>   personal pronoun “I”: “I think …”, “I am.” You yourself have done the
>   same thing, and in other circumstances as well. You have never
>   referred to yourself any differently, except when talking to your
>   young children; then instead of saying “I” you said “Papa” or “Mama”.
>   Sometimes you may have said “your servant” instead of “I”, but that
>   was only for fun. ([Source](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/9780429259388/chapters/10.4324/9780429259388-1))

There are two meanings for "homology", one in biology ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(biology))) and the other in mathematics. None of them seems to me to fit here. What is your view?

Comment: What are the two meanings that you found that don’t apply exactly? How do would you express those meanings on your own words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "homology" is not at all common, but its definition is based on common Greek roots.  It is the noun form of the slightly more common term "homologous":

> [**homologous**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/homologous) (adj):  having the same position, value, structure, etc.," 1650s, from Latinized form of Greek *homologos* "agreeing, of one mind," from *homos* "same" + *logos* "relation, reasoning, computation"

All of the various usages in biology, etc. rely on this underlying definition, namely, "having the same structure".  The specific "homology" referred to seems to be that fact that both you and Rene Descartes use the same personal pronoun "I".  It is an academic term, which the author uses to suggests that "you" (the subject of his narrative) analyze the observation with a logical/scientific frame of mind.

I would need to read more to understand where the author is going with this argument, and whether it is accurate to describe this as a "homology".